# Magento catalog price rule

Tags: magento2, collection, catalog-rules

How to get product based on conditions on catalog rule in magento2?

By product model products are received but how to apply filter to get only those product based on conditions.

Any help will be appreciated.

Thanks,

Answer (score 0):

You can get some help from this referance link: 
https://www.mageplaza.com/devdocs/how-to-get-list-product-from-catalog-rule-condition-in-magento-2.html